# Spring context.xml file cannot be opened because it doesn't exist?

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

I'm experimenting with spring and I can't figure out why it cannot locate the spring-context.xml file that's in the same package.

[image]

When I use "classpath*:spring-context.xml" instead, it seems to have found the file but then I get an error that "No bean named "vehicle" has been defined, while I believe I did define it.

[image]

Comment: Normally when you load a resource from your class and the resource is in the same package (for example com.mavin1) you need to pass the path to the package as well: "com/mavin1/spring-context.xml".

I am aware if ClassPathXmlApplicationContext requires this, but give it a try.
Change your line 14 and add "com/mavin1/" in front of the filename.

Another comment - do not use screenshots here. Paste the text so it can be searched and copied.

Comment: Non java files need to be in `src/main/resources` **not** `src/main/java`. If they are in the latter Maven will ignore them and makes them unavailable.